# How git is pushing tag changes and fast forward merges?

Tags: git

Some background, I want to be able to push tags or make fast forward merges without having a local repo.

As I see from other questions this is not supported out of the box with git commands.

But I'm wondering what is being sent as part of a git protocol to add a new tag ? and what are the protocol commands to fast forward branch on a remote?

Answer (score 1):

You would need for the remote repo to be hosted by a service able to listen to such queries and to execute them for you.

That would avoid you to have any local  cloned repo.

For example, The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) allows you to **[update a ref](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference)**:

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref
```

You also can [create tag](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) with the same API (but other Git repo hosting service also provide similar API, like the [Bitbucket one](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs)).

That would apply, of course, only if your remote repo is on GitHub.

But you cannot do the same with git alone and no local repo.